# KVM/QEMU emulation of processor virtualization features

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu, amd-v

I'm finding the developer documentation of KVM/QEMU to be weak/nonexistent and cannot actually find the answer to this question anywhere, does KVM/QEMU or any other virtualization product yet support emulating the AMD-V or VT-x processor features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the answer. The term as one guy said was "nested virtualization". For kvm/kqemu pass the parameter -enable-nesting. Currently only amd is supported though.  Now my problem is that it still does not allow xen to run as a hypervisor because xen crashes ion boot.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC KVM has been able to do nested virtualization for a while on AMD and only recently on Intel processors. Better ask this on the kvm mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

Wind River Simics can provide a virtual machine with full VT-x support, from Simics 4.6.  I know it can run Xen, as well the Wind River Hypervisor, on a fully virtual x86 target.